# c++ what does a dynamic cast of a unique pointer return?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, smart-pointers, dynamic-cast

I am trying to use lambdas to find a way to find how many specific derived classes are in a vector of Base class type.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Account>> openedAccounts;

int countCurrent = std::count_if(openedAccounts.begin(), openedAccounts.end(), 
            [](std::unique_ptr<Account> ptr) { return dynamic_cast<Current&>(*ptr) != nullptr; }); // I will call this for savings as well
```

The account is a base abstract class and the current is a derived class.

I am getting the error `no operator != matches these operands".`
HOwever, I thought dynamic cast can return a null ptr.

Comment: You're casting to a reference, comparing with a pointer type. References can't be `nullptr`.

Comment: Problem here is that you are trying to do a copy of `unique_ptr`. As name suggest `unique_ptr` is unique, you can't do a copy of it. Lambda must be `[](const std::unique_ptr<Account>& ptr)`

Comment: @HattedRooster what is the way to go about this then?

Comment: @MarekR That's not it

Comment: Just cast to a pointer and check from there.

Comment: @HattedRooster as with unique pointers I can do it by * only by reference.

Comment: @HattedRooster when he fix cast problem, problem I described will pop up.

Comment: Anyway if you have to do dynamic_cast (especially in such context) then your selection of abstraction is wrong. You have more general problem.

Comment: @MarekR why would it be wrong?

Comment: The whole point of OOP is that you can handle objects without knowing what is their type. When you have to check type, it breaks OOP and your code has some entanglement to a specific type, so what is the reasoning to have abstraction here?

Comment: "how many specific derived classes" This rarely makes sense (and is a big red no-no if you subscribe to OO design philosophy).

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic cast returns exactly what you asked for.

You asked for `Current&` or a Current reference.

You probably want to ask this

```
return dynamic_cast<Current*>(ptr.get()) != nullptr;
```

Comment: Thank you, it gets rid of my error now! does the rest of my code seem ok?

Comment: From glancing over, yes.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought dynamic cast can return a null ptr.

Only when you dynamic cast into a pointer type.

References don't have a representation for null. When you dynamic cast into a reference type, then an exception will be thrown in cases where a pointer cast would have returned null.

> what is the way to go about this then?

```
dynamic_cast<Current*>(ptr.get())
```

would work. However, designs that require `dynamic_cast` are often probably bad. `dynamic_cast` exists for mostly working around badly designed APIs.

I recommend considering alternative designs.

Comment: I not using any API's just a simple console-based banking system which I need to find a way to find how many derived class objects are in a vector of the base type.

Comment: Can you expand further on this, as I'm trying to also understand lambdas is it possible to do it with lambdas?

Comment: @paigelarry342 Lambdas don't have inheritance hierarchies. I don't understand how they relate to your problem.

Comment: @paigelarry342 The `typeid` suggestion was bad. I didn't understand what you said first.

Comment: Ok but how would type_id fix my problem? can you explain

Comment: @paigelarry342 See my previous comment. It wouldn't. It would solve another problem that I thought you had because I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Ok i think a better way to do this is to define a std:string protected member in Account and have the derived classes set a name to that member, and I can check the name for each object, would this be good?

Comment: @paigelarry342 What you're doing is probably one of the less bad uses of `dynamic_cast`, but I do recommend exploring alternative solutions as well. See how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

> ```cpp
> std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Account>> openedAccounts;
>
> int countCurrent = std::count_if(openedAccounts.begin(), openedAccounts.end(), 
>             [](std::unique_ptr<Account> ptr) { return dynamic_cast<Current&>(*ptr) != nullptr; }); // I will call this for savings as well
> ```

I see in this code 3 problems:

1. `dynamic_cast<Current&> ... != nullptr` - `dynamic_cast` throws an exception for references and never returns `null_ptr`.
2. Lambda is incorrect, since argument `std::unique_ptr<Account>` is an attempt to create a copy of something what should be unique.
3. if you have container of pointers to some abstraction and you have to do `dynamic_cast` then this is clear indication that abstraction used is invalid.

So this should look looks more like this:

```cpp
class Account {
public:
    virtual bool isCurrent() { return false; }
    ....
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Account>> openedAccounts;

int countCurrent = std::count_if(openedAccounts.begin(), openedAccounts.end(), 
            [](const std::unique_ptr<Account>& ptr) { return ptr->isCurrent(); });
```

I undesutnd that last point is hard to process so here is the hacky fix:

```cpp
int countCurrent = std::count_if(openedAccounts.begin(), openedAccounts.end(), 
            [](const std::unique_ptr<Account>& ptr) { return dynamic_cast<Current *>(ptr.get()) != nullptr; });
```

Comment: @thank you but is your first solution the better way to do it?

Comment: In general yes, since first code do not have to use `Current` type at all (no dependency) and this is main feature of OOP. I do not know details of your code so I do not know how much stuff you have to correct to make it work.

Comment: Ok thanks, and also for the virtual bool would it not be best to make it pure virtual? and just override it in my current and savings class?